# Extend a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to a function $h:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t they share stationary points along x=y

Tags: calculus

Lets say I have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then I make an extension to a function $h: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x,y) = f(x)$ along the line $x=y$ i.e $h(x,x) = f(x)$

Now assume I'm looking for stationary points of $h(x,y)$ alonge the line $x=y$ when will they be equal to the stationary points of $f$? Or perphaps that can never be the case?

Comment: Is $h$ some particular choice or just any function satisfying $h(x,x) = f(x)$?

Comment: Let $f(x) = x^{3-\ln x}$ then take $h(x,y) = x^{3 - \ln y}$. Here we have $\partial_x = (\ln (y) - 3)(-x^{2 - \ln(x)})$ and $\partial_y =  -\frac{\ln (x) x^{3-\ln (y)}}{y}$. @user251257

Comment: How are those two equal? @user251257

Comment: Ah, a typo was in my comment. Sorry

Comment: Notice that $f'(x) = h_x(x,x) + h_y(x,x) = e^T \nabla h(x,x)$.